# Loop is interrupted by a value

Tags: c

This is my problem: I am simulating a particle random walking ((my full codes are long)) in a spherical region (of radius 0.5, with a reflective boundary outside) with absorbing boundary at radius r = 0.05. It starts at r = 0.25 and the loop will stop when it hits the absorbing boundary. However, the loops are always interrupted by value 1.#QNAN000000000000. For example, I am writting the distance to the origin in a file:

... ... (a lot of numbers omitted)

0.20613005432153597

0.20623630547871444

0.20638287597603161

0.20639479244526721

0.20632936118972162

0.20624097359751253

0.20634346836172857

0.20662686334789271

0.20662651327072232

0.20661986008216310

0.20662358691463298

0.20661462509258177

0.20649145569824909

0.20651885241720047

0.20652145059961324

0.20651490447436160

0.20646925001041655

0.20645889385120675

0.20629285654651422

0.20633769635178317

0.20635757642249095

0.20645451482187596

0.20654217470043859

1.#QNAN000000000000

Here the problem arises, the particle is not yet absorbed, but 1.#QNAN000000000000 interrupts the loop. I vaguely know that this might be due to issues in arithmetric operations of floats, but I am paying considerable attention to this. Therefore, I am wondering what I should probably do to avoid these kind of things? Thanks a lot!

As debugger, I printed out the values of many variables when the probolem arises. It turns out that all these variables are either 1.#QNAN000000000000 or 1.#INF000000000000.

Comment: I am using DEV C++ under windows

Comment: You should pay even more attention? How could we help you fix your problem when you're not showing any of the relevant code?

Comment: I just added the relevant part of the codes.

Comment: No, you've pasted a whole bunch of code with no indication of where the bug is. Use a debugger or printfs to find out exactly where you're producing NaNs. Post only the relevant part, with the relevant data (i.e. what values the variables have before producing that NaN) if you can't figure things out yourself once you've narrowed it down.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I finally found the problem: In generating gaussian random numbers, I used log(u) instead of log(1-u), and u might be 0.